# Word for grain ready to be harvested

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word for grain, or produce in general, that is ready to be harvested? I was considering *ripe*, but this gives the connotation of completely ready and edible, and doesn't seem to be related to the harvest.

Comment: I think "ripe" is the word.

Comment: A dictionary definition for ripe includes the maturity of fruits and grains. http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/ripe; therefore, ripe should be good.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with 'ripe', 'mature', 'fully-grown' and similar terms is that some produce is picked before it is ripe (mature, fully-grown, etc.), and some produce is picked after it is ripe. This is true not only for contemporary agriculture, in a millieu when techniques for ripening already-harvested produce have been refined and extended to accommodate the transportation needs of a world-wide market; it is also true of agriculture historically.

This, the harvest of unripe, immature produce (or the converse, overripe produce), is as true of grain as it is of many other types of produce. Here's an example of both the historical and contemporary cases:

> Way, way back — as in, pre-biblical back — in time. Try the ancient grain called, variously, freekeh, frikh, farik or freek. It's actually **unripe durum wheat, harvested green** and then burned to rid it of its husk. The burning imbues the grain with a slight smoky flavor.

(From ["The new (ancient) grain"](http://articles.chicagotribune.com/2013-07-31/features/sc-food-0726-freekeh-20130731_1_grain-new-season-mediterranean), *Chicago Tribune*, July 31, 2013. Emphasis mine.)

The term 'harvest-ready' is commonly used in modern agriculture to preserve the distinction between produce that is ripe and produce that is ready to harvest, whether or not the produce is ripe.

'Harvest-ready' means just what would be supposed from the two words compounded:

> ready to harvest.

That the compound 'harvest-ready' is in common use (although not readily found in dictionaries) is evidenced by the approximately 167 million hits the exact term search ([+harvest-ready](https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=%2Bharvest-ready&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)) produces in Google.

Comment: There is no problem with the picking of immature crops if that is the state in which they are harvested. OED: Etymology: Cognate with West Frisian ryp , †rijp , Middle Dutch rīpe , rijp , riep (Dutch rijp ), Old Saxon rīp , rīpi (Middle Low German rīpe , German regional (Low German) rīp ), Old High German rīfi , rīfe (Middle High German rīf , rīfe , German reif ), all showing a similar range of meanings < the same Germanic base as reap v.1 (see discussion at that entry), probably with original sense *‘that which is (ready to be) reaped or harvested’.*

Answer (score 9):

*ripe (for harvest)* is correct; it's been used even as long ago as the bible.

> I tell you, open your eyes and look at the fields! They are ripe for harvest. - John 4:35
>
> IN STATE APPLE ORCHARDS, TIME IS RIPE FOR HARVEST. - NYT

[Ripe](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ripe):

> (top definition) fully grown and developed: mature   - MW

As most wheat is not eaten off the stalk, I think it adequately implies harvest.

Comment: Was bible written in English?

Comment: Weird, not sure why someone would down vote this. It answers the question and provides a link to a dictionary.

Comment: @user3885927 - Seriously? Were *you* aware that it was translated into English hundreds of years ago?

Comment: you should probably speak to a specific translation of bible rather than bible itself.

Comment: @user3885927 The Koine word used 2000 years ago was λευκός, which means white or bright, and from the KJV 400 years ago (possibly in the earlier English versions too, I haven't looked, it. Has mostly been translated as "white for harvest" (formal equivalence) or "ripe for harvest" (dynamic equivalence).

Comment: @DanielStowers - Oops, thanks for that. I think in the jump to Virgil, I didn't explain the middle step.

Answer (score 2):

Next to *ripe*, which indeed is correct, you might want to consider ***full-grown***. [Google Books](https://www.google.fr/search?q=%22crop+is+full%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en&gws_rd=cr,ssl&ei=UTVOVu3gM4utabWQqJAL#lr=lang_en&tbs=lr:lang_1en&tbm=bks&q=%22crop+is+full-grown%22)

> full-grown:  having reached full growth or development :  mature [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/full-grown)

Comment: This runs into the same problem as the OP finds with *ripe*. When baby carrots or microgreens are ready for harvest they are not full-grown.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about a field of grain (especially wheat) it is common to say that the field is white.

Comment: Influenced, most likely, by λευκαί (white) in John 4:35 More English translations say "white" (inc. KJV) than say "ripe."

Answer (score -1):

In Revelation 14v15, the Greek word *exeranthe* is used and is translated into our English word "ripe". It comes from the Greek verb *xeraino* meaning to dry up. This shows the harvest is ready for reaping.

> In the last days, sin will have reached its peak in the world, the Gospel of the Grace of God will have been rejected by the majority (who will gladly have received the mark of the beast) and the day of God's wrath will be like a harvest for judgement.

The word *ripe* is used again in verse 18 to translate another Greek word *akmazō* which means *mature* and refers to grapes full of juice, ready for the winepress, which is the opposite of *dried* as in the case of grain.

I suppose that in 1611, when the authorised version of the Bible was translated, the word *ripe* simply meant *ready for harvest*, whether for grain or grapes.

Comment: I suspect that the question was hoping for an English rather than Greek word.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/426540)

Comment: I think I have now answered the question from the use of the word in a well established source.